# Is it possible to open a URL in an external browser from within HTML component?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm loading a webpage inside a HTML component in AIR. By default, when something is clicked the next page is loaded inside the HTML component itself. I want the links from that page to open in an external web browser.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the property navigateInSystemBrowser. Check this code:

```
        private changeHtmlLoaderBehaviour():void
        {

            html.htmlLoader.navigateInSystemBrowser = true;
        }
        <mx:HTML id="html"..location="http://www.amazon.com"../>
```